# What does list() function do to an iterable object?

Tags: python

Can someone please explain what happens to the `map` object? Why is the second `list` empty?

```
res = map(lambda x: 1 + x, range(1,5))
print (list(res))
print (list(res))
```

Result:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[]
```

Comment: `res` is a generator that you're exhausting first time you're making it a list.

Comment: The second line exhausts the `map` object. Or in other words: it has finished doing its job.